# Line segment k-intersection

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Could you please help me to design the following algorithm:

I have a random-access list of line segments defined by a pair of points $[x^s_i; x^e_i]$. The list is initially unsorted, but of course can be sorted by left or right coordinate in $n \log n$.

I need to determine whether at least $k$ of these segments intersect or not as quick as possible (asymptotically).

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you want a manual method or an algorithm?

Comment: @Emmad: "random-access list" was sorta kinda a tipoff that OP intends to do this on a computer...

Comment: What do you mean when you say $k$ of them intersect?  You could mean that there is a point contained in $k$ segments.  You could mean that there are $k$ lines each of which intersects the $k-1$ others.  You could mean that there are $k$ lines that form a connected component.  You could mean that there are at least $k$ intersections.  You could mean something else entirely  It is likely that some variant of Bentley Ottman search will serve your purpose.

Comment: At first I though this would be easy, but when I looked at the link below, I found that it is not trivial (if you have many segments) - The link is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection

Comment: @Emmad, that link concerns line segments in the plane. I may be misreading here, but I think OP is asking about line segments on a line, which might be a much easier problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, wow, I did not think of this!

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the question this way (and if I've misinterpreted, kindly ignore this answer): you have $n$ inequalities of the form $$a_i\le x\le b_i$$ and you want to know whether there is an $x$ that satisfies at least $k$ of them. If there is such an $x$, then there is an $a_i$ that satisfies $k$ of them (there's also a $b_i$ that satisfies at least $k$ of them), so all you have to do is check each of the $a_i$ to see if it works.

Well, this reduces it to a finite problem, thought whether it is fast enough for your purposes, let alone optimal, I cannot say.